# How to set request header in google ads api

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I want to propose a budget for an ads account under my manager account. I have the following YAML file:

```
developer_token: 13245
login-customer-id: 1324567891
customer-id: 1324567891
user_agent:  13245
client_id: 13245
client_secret: 13245
refresh_token: 13245
```

When i try to run my script, i get this error:

Error with message

> "User doesn't have permission to access customer. Note: If you're accessing a
> client customer, the manager's customer id must be set in the 'login-customer-id' header.

This is the code that i use, from the example python library:

```
    try:
    account_budget_proposal_response = (
      account_budget_proposal_service.mutate_account_budget_proposal(
          customer_id, account_budget_proposal_operation))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the error message you received. It's a little confusing and it got me too.

In your case, both of the below are the same:
**login-customer-id: 1324567891

customer-id: 1324567891**

These need to be different.
**login-customer-id: <- Set the CID of your Manager Account here

customer-id: 1324567891 <- Set the CID of the actual Google Ads Account you want to manage here.**

Comment: What if there are multiple clients and want to fetch data one by one?

Comment: What would be the use case for that? Multiple API clients or multiple client accounts?