# google ads API authentication failed - "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Tags: google-oauth, google-ads-api

My question is the same as described here:
[How to set request header in google ads api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63445982/how-to-set-request-header-in-google-ads-api)
but I'm still facing the problem.
I'm trying to make an API call to google ads. I tried Rest API as well as google.ads.google_ads library. Both ways fail.
I followed all Oath2 steps and got all ids, tokens, secrets, etc.
The Rest API call is :

```
refresh_token = MY_REFRESH_TOKEN
customer_id = 7868******
developer_token = MY_DEVELOPER_TOKEN
access_token =  MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
url = 'https://googleads.googleapis.com/v6/customers/{}/campaignBudgets:mutate'.format(customer_id)

headers = {'developer-token':developer_token,"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(access_token),'login-customer-id':'2693******',"Content-Type": "application/json"}
response = requests.post(url,headers = headers)
print(response.text)
```

and this is the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Why? I provided an access token.

I also tried the "google-ads" code I found in the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/reporting/example
I generated a googleads.ymal file, with the following content:

```
developer_token: MY_DEVELOPER_TOKEN
user_agent: MY_COMPANY_NAME
client-id: 7868******
login-customer-id: 2693******
client_id: MY_CLIENT_ID
client_secret: MY_CLIENT_SECRET
refresh_token: MY_REFRESH_TOKEN
```

and this is what I get:

```
Error with message "User doesn't have permission to access customer. Note: If you're accessing a client customer, the manager's customer id must be set in the 'login-customer-id' header
```

and again I don't understand why. My user was the one to generate all login details, and it has access to the manager account, which listed as "login-customer-id".

Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RestAPI to integrate Google Ads API, try testing this first using postman to make your you are getting response before developing a code in any language.

Follow the following steps to generate the authentication token in postman

1. Set the request URL to **https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token**
2. Method should be **POST**
3. check x-www-form-urlencoded in body section and fill the following
   Key: grant_type      Value: refresh_token
   Key: client_id       Value: your client id
   Key: client_secret   Value: your client secret
   Key: refresh_token   Value: your refresh token

You are all setup to generate authentication token. Click send button to send request to receive access token (See the picture below).
[image]
Now create another request with your endpoint and use the generated access token in this request.

In this example, I am using endpoint to get customers.

1. Set URL to https://googleads.googleapis.com/v6/customers/your client customer id without hyphen.
2. Method **Get**
3. set Headers
   Key: Authorization        Value: Bearer access token you generated above
   Key: developer-token      Value: your developer token
   Key: login-customer-id    Value: Manager Account customer ID without hyphen

Once you get 200 response with customer details, start developing the code.

Comment: Can I use postman for testing all Google ads api endpoint? If so please provide postman collection link.

Comment: @mdsamual Here is the link where you would be able to find Rest methods https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/rest/common/overview

Comment: https://googleads.googleapis.com/v6/customers/customerid-without-hyphen/googleAds:search  (Please note that this link would provide you to customize number of results per request by using pageSize parameter)

Comment: https://googleads.googleapis.com/v6/customers/3072947393/googleAds:searchStream (This link would bring all results in one request)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have admin access to the manager account?

Comment: No, I have "standard", and I've been told it should be sufficient. Do I have to have an admin access?

Answer (score 0):

I had the account manager role and was catching the same error.
I solved the problem by simply specifying the API version when creating the client

```
client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_dict(cred_dict, version="v9")
```

After that, I was able to get data on accounts
Creeds like that

```
cred_dict = {
'developer_token': '---------',
'refresh_token': '------',
'client_id': '-------',
'client_secret': '-----',
'access_token': '------',
'use_proto_plus': False,
'login_customer_id': '-----'}
```