# Where can I get Google Ads API URL endpoints to call on Postman?

Tags: java, node.js, rest, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I want to call Google Ads APIs on Postman/through my own code without their libraries. I am searching for the REST endpoint but unable to find it.
Link for the doc: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start. As I have called the sample API successfully and I have got 200 for that. Just want help in finding REST API URLs for Google Ads API(v6)

Answer (score 0):

There is only one URL that is used to generate any queries.

Please check the same link you mentioned above and follow the screen shot.

[image]

[image]

Also, check my answer to the following link where I have explained how to generate access token and use url to make calls using Postman.

[google ads API authentication failed - "PERMISSION_DENIED"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65128638/google-ads-api-authentication-failed-permission-denied/66189403?noredirect=1#comment117023511_66189403)

Check the comments also.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how can I link client account to my manager account? programmtically